# Inconvenient though this might sound, ... phrase structure

Tags: grammar

> The value of $_inputType is set internally by the class at the time of instantiating the
>   object. If you attempt to change it directly, PHP generates a fatal error, bringing everything
>   to a grinding halt. **Inconvenient though this might sound**, this preserves the integrity of
>   your code by preventing an attacker from tricking a validation routine to handle variables
>   from the wrong type of source.

Does this type of phrasing sound alright to you as native speakers of English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely , it's just the way that the writer/author chose to form his sentence , sure he could right like "Inconvenient this might sound" but the other way round is popularly used in poetry etc to be more catchy.